# Use the same query for multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have this two similar queries for different tables, one for loan_offers table and one for special_offers table

for loan_offers

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT " +
                "CAST(o.id AS VARCHAR), o.user_id, " +
                "o.partner_key, o.partner_name, " +
                "o.originator_key, o.originator_name, " +
                "o.type, o.response, " +
                "COALESCE(lo.recommendation_score, 0) AS recommendation_score " +
                "FROM offers o " +
                "INNER JOIN loan_offers lo " +
                "ON lo.offer_id = o.id " +
                "WHERE o.created_at > EXTRACT(epoch FROM now() - INTERVAL '30' DAY) * 1000 " +
                "AND o.user_id = ?1 " +
                "ORDER BY recommendation_score DESC",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<OffersResponse> fetchLoanOffers(String userId);
```

for special_offers

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT " +
                "CAST(o.id AS VARCHAR), o.user_id, " +
                "o.partner_key, o.partner_name, " +
                "o.originator_key, o.originator_name, " +
                "o.type, o.response, " +
                "COALESCE(so.recommendation_score, 0) AS recommendation_score " +
                "FROM offers o " +
                "INNER JOIN special_offers so " +
                "ON so.offer_id = o.id " +
                "WHERE o.created_at > EXTRACT(epoch FROM now() - INTERVAL '30' DAY) * 1000 " +
                "AND o.user_id = ?1 " +
                "ORDER BY recommendation_score DESC",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<OffersResponse> fetchSpecialOffers(String userId);
```

So my question is how not to write so much similar code, maybe by using UDF or there is a better solution.

Comment: You could LEFT JOIN both loan_offers and special_offers, but add a parameter (`AND`) in the ON clauses to select one or the other (`AND 'LO'=?2, and AND 'SO'=?2), and use the 2nd parameter to decide which LEFT JOIN returns rows (if you pass 'LO' in ?2 it will be loan_offers, and so on).

Comment: This suggests a slight design change could avoid this issue.  The shown detail is identical.  You've complicated your SQL by creating two identical tables instead of creating one table with a `type` column.  Without the rest of the schema, it's tough to propose a solution to your real problem.  Try adding the `CREATE TABLE` statements in your question.

Comment: @JonArmstrong but there is some non-nullable fields in loan_offers table, which are not contained in special_offers table, so how can I merge them two ?

Comment: Refactor the attributes common to all offers and place the optional non-common attributes in another table with a reference to the common offer detail.  If it helps to have a separate offer_type column in the common table, add one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to declare which table you want and use the variable in the query string. Change the alias of the table to be the same and it looks like it'd be the same query.

I don't really recommend it though as they are different tables that could change and the circumstances for the need. Its better to have the defined query for its use in a business object or something.
But we do these things to save typing some times.